# Python need to thread a certain function

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, raspberry-pi2

First off i want to mention i have been watching videos and trying my best to understand how to make threads work but i cannot figure it out. I'm hoping someone can make this work for me in my particular situation and i can learn from it or at the very least just make it work for me.

I want the start_timer function to be a threaded process so the user can still activate other functions while this one is running.

Eventually each function will be associated with a button in tkinter and send info to my raspberry pi to control the watering of my garden.

Here is my code:

```
import time


class Valve:

    def __init__(self, pin, location):
        self.pin = pin
        self.location = location

    timer = 0
    status = False

    def turn_on(self):
        self.status = True
        self.send_info()

    def turn_off(self):
        self.status = False
        self.send_info()

    def set_timer(self, minutes):
        self.timer = minutes * 60

    def start_timer(self):
        self.turn_on()
        self.status = True
        while self.timer > 0:
            print(self.timer)
            self.timer -= 1
            time.sleep(1)
        self.turn_off()


    def send_info(self):
        print("sending this info to server:", self.pin, self.status)

hose1 = Valve(1, 'Garden')
hose2 = Valve(2, 'Lawn')


hose1.set_timer(1)

hose1.start_timer()

hose2.turn_on()
```

I thought that replacing hose1.start_timer() with the below would work but it still runs this hole process before hose2.turn_on() get executed.

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=hose1.start_timer(), args=hose1.timer)
thread.start()
```

Thanks whoever can make this work for me!

Also if anybody is interested in this project i would love to have a partner to bounce ideas back and forth with during the creation of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling your thread wrong.

You need to use

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=hose1.start_timer, args=(hose1.timer, ))
```

or

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=lambda: hose1.start_timer(), args=(hose1.timer,))
```

If you want the thread to exit when the program does, since this is tkinter, that would be most likely the root window.

You can set the thread to be a daemon using `thread.daemon = True` and then you can call `thread.start()`

Comment: i used the top one and noticed i completely brain farted as i didn't need any arguments so i removed that and now it seems to be working!